# Can not remove teamviewer (no permissions)

Tags: 14.04, teamviewer

I can't deinstall software anymore (it says I have no rights to do so) and there is a teamviewer process showing up if I use `top`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login as root and type `dpkg -l|grep -i team`, the output should contain the package name of the teamviewer package. Then use `dpkg --purge <packetname>` to remove it. If this doesn't work, edit your question and add the error message, I'll then edit my answer.

```
dpkg: Fehler: Angeforderte Operation benötigt Superuser-Rechte
```

You are not root, you're the user `nuc`. Use `su -` to become root first, or use `sudo`.

Comment: I posted the output above.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Okay, I removed both teamviewer9 and steam-launcher. I'm not allowed to deinstall anything in the software-center still.

Comment: steam-launcher is for the steam platform (gaming stuff). Please open an new question for the software-center problem (do you need to execute this as root?)